# numpy.format seems to just round to an integer

Tags: python, numpy

im trying to format this list so it stays in scientific notation but has fewer decimals.but the script below seems to just round everything to the nearest integer

```
import numpy
A=[9.380726789802627885e-23, 9.764534271051429814448e-23, 1.0168775777415136679e-22, 1.0573873175565650064e-22, 1.098630609702e-2, 1.14060439559859689e-22]
B=[]
for i in range(len(A)):
    c=numpy.format_float_scientific(i, precision=5)
    B.append(c)
print(B)
```

B prints out as

```
['0.e+00', '1.e+00', '2.e+00', '3.e+00', '4.e+00', '5.e+00']
```

am i misunderstanding "precision"?

Comment: Looks like you're passing in the counter (i, precision=5), not the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in A:
```

fixes your code, but then you should rename `i` to something more meaningful.

Your `range(len(A))` is actually `range(6)` which is equivalent (not completely, in Python 3.x) to `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, which is where the output of your code comes from.

Maybe you forgot to write `A[i]` instead of `i` as as the first argument of `format_float_scientific`. But this would have been an inefficient way of looping over your list.

The most “pythonic” way to get the same result would be through the use of a list comprehension, but the comprehension of comprehensions is not always easy, and you can live without them for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is incorrect.  In your code it should look something like

```
import numpy
A=[9.380726789802627885e-23, 9.764534271051429814448e-23, 
   1.0168775777415136679e-22, 1.0573873175565650064e-22, 
   1.098630609702e-2, 1.14060439559859689e-22]
B=[]
for i in A:
    c=numpy.format_float_scientific(i, precision=5)
    B.append(c)
print(B)
```

You could also have a cleaner solution utilizing a list comprehension:

```
B = [numpy.format_float_scientific(i, precision=5) for i in A]
```

Both will give you the desired output.